# Git: remote rejected, unable to migrate objects to permanent storage

Tags: git

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin 
feature/xxx:feature/xxx
POST git-receive-pack (3470 bytes)
Pushing to http://xxx@stash/xxx.git
To http://stash/xxx.git
! [remote rejected] feature/xxx -> feature/xxx (unable to migrate objects 
to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'http://xxx@stash/xxx.git'


Completed with errors, see above.
```

Could someone explain how to go about troubleshooting this error? I've looked as some other similar questions but I can't find anything that helps work out why this push is being rejected- I literally updated the branch about half an hour earlier and wanted to push a new file I'd forgotten to include in the initial push. I've tried updating dev then switching back to the feature branch I'm working on as some comments suggested that git tries to update differences between other local branches and the remotes, but that hasn't done anything- I get exactly the same error message as before.

Comment: Have you tried performing a `git fetch`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `unable to migrate objects to permanent storage` is typically the result of a configuration error on the server.  In any case it's quite likely that nothing you do on your end will improve the result.

When a server receives a `git push`, the receiving Git gets, from the sending side, a series of Git objects—commits, trees, blobs, and/or tags, all of which make up the content sent from whoever is doing the `git push`.  Then the sender delivers a request: *I'd like you, the receiver, to *name* these objects with some particular branch and/or tag names, so that they become accessible.*

In Git versions before 2.11.0, the *objects* immediately went into the receiver's object database.  Then the receiver would inspect the suggested name creation or update (e.g., `feature/xxx` should point to object `1234567...`), verify whether it was OK, and either do the update and reply *OK, done* or reject the update with a specific error, e.g., "not fast forward".

In Git version 2.11.0, the process has changed: incoming objects are placed in a "quarantine zone" until the name update(s) are accepted.  Once the receiver verifies that updating `feature/xxx` is OK, the receiver has to *move* the objects from the quarantine area into the object database.  Once the move succeeds and the update is done, you get the *OK, done* reply from the server.

It's this movement, from quarantine zone within repository to repository object database, that is failing.  In other words, there's *nothing wrong with your push request*.  Instead, the server is saying: *I would have done as you asked, but I've fallen over and cannot fix myself.*

To fix the problem, whoever controls the server should log in to the machine and inspect the repository area, paying particular attention to file and directory ownership and permissions, disk quotas, and anything else that might affect this object migration process.

Comment: Thanks- that's a good overview of how it works. It did turn out to be a permissions issue as you suggested. The virtual machine where the repository is based was started as root apparently, so the repository permissions had to be reset before I could push. Thanks again for the description of what was going on.